# Fading in and out effect takes action only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid of images (3X4), on button click, I want to display another category of images on the same grid. I added a fade out and in effect, so the old images fade out, loading the new images and fading in the grid. My problem is that it only happens once, after that, clicking another category button, won't play the effect, the images just change. This is my code:

```
    //Fading out the mainGrid
function fadeMainGrid(){ 
    if (isShowingMainGrid) { 
        $('#picturesGrid').removeClass('animated fadeIn')
        $('#picturesGrid').addClass('animated fadeOut')
        isShowingMainGrid = !isShowingMainGrid
    }else { 
        $('#picturesGrid').removeClass('animated fadeOut')
        $('#picturesGrid').addClass('animated fadeIn')
        isShowingMainGrid = !isShowingMainGrid
    }
}

function displayGalleryOf(buttonId) { 
    fadeMainGrid()
    switch(buttonId) { 
        case 'button1':
            displayGallery('CAT1')
            break;
        case 'button2':
            displayGallery('CAT2')
            break;
        case 'button3':
            displayGallery('CAT3')
            break;
        case 'button4':
            displayGallery('CAT4')
            break;
        default:
            displayGallery('CAT1')
    }
}

function displayGallery(galleryName) { 
    //TODO: Load thumbnail of the image to reduce lag.

    let src = './Images/' + galleryName + '/';
    let myGridCells = $('.foodImage')

    for(var i=0; i<myGridCells.length; i++){
        let newSrc = src + i + '.jpg';
        myGridCells[i].src = newSrc;
    }

    fadeMainGrid();

}
```

Comment: Off-topic advice: Reduce your duplicated selector and class values to just this... `$('#picturesGrid').removeClass('fadeIn').addClass('fadeOut');`

Comment: You might need to show us your markup (or [a demo](https://jsfiddle.net)). There may be something there that's problematic.

Comment: You omitted to post main part of code and that is the button click event - and I can tell you there is the error... cause you probably remove buttons, so the event vanish. So you need event delegation etc... also you need you rework your code, those switch statements pretty su.. in there :) cheers

Comment: @skobalijc The OP doesn't say that the grid replacement doesn't work, only the fadein, and the fadein effect is called by a function in the swap function itself. Main part missing is the css. Im curious about the animated class.

Comment: @iguypouf the animated class is taken from the jQuery, If I need to add something else, please let me know, I'm really new to JS and web technologies in general, so I didn't really knew what I should upload.

Comment: Please share the CSS for fadeIn and fadeOut class. Obviously they are responsible for the fading in/out effect, not the javascript. I do suggest using JQuery's fadein() and fadeout().

Comment: @NawedKhan I'm using now JQuery's fadein and fadeout.

Comment: @JohnDoah is it working as you want it to work? If not, then please update the question to include how you are using fadein and fadeout.

Comment: @NawedKhan It is still not working as I want, the fadein and fadeout are JQuery's.